# Ways of adding elements to collections

Tags: c#, list, collections

Just being curious, I saw a two ways of creating collections in C#. For me it's just an style but maybe there's another explanation. Performance? Does this correspond to a pattern? The only thing that I can see in the example 2, it's a way to prevent an overwrite of the collection.

Example 1:

```
public class Employee
{
   ...
   public List<Phone> Phones
   {
      get; set;
   }
   ...
}
```

So. from another class

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.Phones = this.GetPhones();
```

Example 2:

```
public class Employee
{
   ...
   private List<Phone> colPhones;
   public List<Phone> Phones
   {
      get
      {
         if(this.Phones == null)
         {
             this.Phones = new List<Phone>();
         }
         return this.Phones;
      }
   }
   ...
   public void AddPhone(Phone phone)
   {
       this.Phones.Add(phone);
   }
}
```

So.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
List<Phone> phones = this.GetPhones();
//--> Here, I know I can use for(int i....) instead of foreach. This is just for the example.
foreach(Phone phone in phones) 
{
   employee.Phones.Add(phone);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I found this link [Encapsulate collection](http://refactoring.com/catalog/encapsulateCollection.html) when I was reading a Martin Fowler's book named "Refactoring" which is the same concept as the accepted answer.

Comment: In example 2 "private List<Phone> colPhones;" looks like it's unused - an artifact of a previous rewrite of the program?

Comment: It should be used. Instead of `this.Phones` inside the `Phones` getter, the OP should be referencing `this.colPholes`. Otherwise, they're going to get a circular reference that will constantly throw StackOverflowExceptions whenever the property is accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your first example is a rather dangerous. You say yourself that it is vulnerable to an "overwrite" of the collection, but I think even more important it is vulnerable to subtle modifications of the collection if you aren't very careful.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
List<Phone> obscureTemporaryVariable = this.GetPhones();
employee.Phones = obscureTemporaryVariable;
...
// much later, after having forgotten all about the above bit of code
obscureTemporaryVariable.Clear();
obscureTemporaryVariable.Add(new Phone(42));
```

Now you've (presumably unintendedly) modified the phone numbers for "employee".

Comment: Also the second example complies better with the "don't talk to strangers" principle.

Comment: Except that both examples allow for modification of any members. If you want to ensure that nothing is ever modified in the collection, then you're going to have to make the property `readonly`, and set it only via a constructor.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I was reading a book named "Refactoring" from Martin Fowler. Here, there is a picture from the book which summarizes it very well. http://refactoring.com/catalog/encapsulateCollection.html I read the motivation of this strategy and it's pretty similar as you said. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When doing the following code, the private member variables are created down in the IL level of the code.

```
public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
```

The second method is a way to implement lazy loading. Typically, instead of doing the `this.Phones = new List<Phone>();`, a method would be provided that would generate the collection from a database. Another reason to use your second scenario would be to not overwrite any existing collection, but avoid having to worry about `NullReferenceException`s when referencing the property.

For 95% of your situations, the first scenario would be fine.

In both examples, there is nothing stopping the consumer of your Employee class to do the following: `employee.Phones.Add(new Phone())`. There is no way to prevent modification of the collection unless you make the property `readonly`, but then you can only set it in the constructor of your `Employee` class, and your `AddPhone()` method will then become unusable.